# heroku limitations and restrictions

Tags: python, django, heroku

I’ve seen a lot about the restrictions Google puts on App Engine, but I have not been able to find much on Heroku limitations and restrictions for comparison. Are there any, and if so, specifically, what are they?

A related question is that I see that Heroku has a marketplace for third party add ons. But if I want a feature covered by one of these add ons, am I limited to using those or can I acquire one from any vendor I choose, or even code it myself? It would make sense that I could code it myself, that’s the whole point of these platforms, but that doesn’t mean there aren’t restrictions, which brings me back to the original question.

FYI, I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.6.1, if that matters to your answer. And I am aware of the performance controversy with rapgenius, but I don’t expect any service to be perfect all the time, so I’m not sure that matters much.

Comment: My understanding of heroku is that it is basically just a wrapper over an aws instance, that provides lots of built in features and connivence methods. It might be the case the the only limitations on heroku are the ones on aws itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find more information on Heroku limits in the [Acceptable Use Policy](https://www.heroku.com/policy/aup). There's also a ["Limits"](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits) article on Dev Center.

You're free to use any service you like from your Heroku apps, whether it's in the add-on catalog, outside it, or whether you're running and hosting it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

- Heroku has a [30 second request timeout](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout), which is not configurable. This means that after 30 seconds the request will be interrupted, but your code will keep running, making this particular dyno unavailable. If the user then refreshes the page and starts the same long-running operation with another dyno, this other dyno may become unavailable as well...
- Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem. This means that you cannot upload files directly to the file system: they will be deleted on restart. You will have to configure external storage to e.g. store your files in the S3 Cloud. Note, however, that this may potentially make your private files public, so I imagine you may need another layer of complexity to e.g. generate a one-time link for the user to use to download a private file, with a very short expiration time. Unless, that is, you implement some custom solution that can pass your user authentication from Heroku to AWS, but then you might just as well host on AWS in the first place.
- For the same reason you cannot use SQLite as a database, as it is file-based. If you do, you will get inconsistent results. Same goes for filesystem-based caching, which is the default for some django libraries. Before I figured it out, I sometimes ended up seeing a different avatar for a user (new or old), presumably depending on which process was serving my request.
- It is not very easy to debug directly on Heroku. You cannot just insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in various places and remotely run `python manage.py runserver` because it won't let you do it for security reasons.